# Zend Framework PHP Solutions

Tags: php, zend-framework, hosting

Hello my fellow Stackoverflownians :),

I just came across this thing called Zend. And it looks pretty cool and i wanna get my hands on it, but I have a question. So if anybody knows anythin about Zend, I would really appreciate your advice.

I am using Winhost as my hosting provider (http://www.winhost.com/) and they are a Windows Hoster, but they also include PHP hosting aswell in their windows packages.

Can Zend be used with WinHost? Or does Zend only work on one of those server apps that you download like Apache or Apremlium etc?

From what I have found its beginning to look likle I cant use it with winhost.

Thank you

Comment: *(overview)* http://www.phpframeworks.com/ and http://www.php-frameworks.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use php on your host, you can use zend framework. That's all it is.

Also, if you think Zend is cool, make sure and take a look at codeigniter. I've used them both a little, and they both have their advantages.

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY I'M GONNA GET ME SOME ZZZZEND! And quite possibly CodeIgniter - Thank you Matthew :D :D :D